# Segmentation fault C++: getline()

Tags: c++, linux

I am writing some C++ code in Linux. The same code works fine in Windows. In Linux, The compilation runs without any errors, but running the code results in a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong here? The following is the part of code where the error occurs

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <numeric>
  #include<cmath>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <string>
  #include <sstream>
  #define FEATURE 27
  using namespace std;
     int main() {
    double features[405];
    double ft_means[FEATURE];
    double ft_std_dev[FEATURE];
    double coefs[405];
    double intercept;
    std::string lines;
    int count;
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("_coefs.txt");
    if (!inputFile)
    cout<< "Error";
    count=0;
    while (std::getline(inputFile, lines) && !lines.empty())
    {
        std::istringstream(lines) >> ft_means[count];
        count++;
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < FEATURE ; i++){
    std::cout << ft_means[i] << std::endl;
    }
         return 0;
     }
```

Using gbd I get this error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b693fa in std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: how many lines are in the file? You can easily overrun the array with this code.

Comment: fwiw, "works there" doesn't really help when it crashes here. If your code has undefined behavior it can appear to work, but it is wrong anywhere

Comment: @idclev463035818 the file has 150 lines, I do the same getline() method 4 times in the script to extract lines from the same text file. The lines are seperated with an empty line.

Comment: @tadman the segmentation fault occurs in that getline() loop

Comment: This looks like a job for `std::vector` and a simple `struct` to hold that data. Seeing numbers like `405` popping up all over is not a good sign. Use arrays you can extend with `push_back`.

Comment: `ft_means[count]` is probably an out of bounds access since `ft_means` has only 27 elements. Instead of using built-in arrays, use `std::vector` instead and `push_back()` new elements into it.

Comment: are you sure that the lines contain nothing but a newline? If there is a tab or a space it would be enough to make your code go nuts

Comment: in any case currently only you can check that. Either use a debugger or put a `std::cout << count << '\n';` inside the loop to see what really happens

Comment: ... oh right "the file has 150 lines" but your array only has space for 27

Comment: @idclev463035818 The text file has much more than 150 lines, actually I read several variables from that text files. The first 27 lines are for  `ft_means`, then comes an empty line so that the first loop stops and the second `getline()` loop starts to fill the second variable.

Comment: what second getline loop? You are taling about code that we cannot see. Please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: Avoid using massive arrays on the stack.....

Comment: There is no guarantee that the loop does indeed stop where it should stop. Are you sure there are exactly 27 non-empty lines in the file? Let the program count them.

Comment: Please show a simple version of  `_coefs.txt` that triggers the problem. Also apply what StPiere's answer below suggests and tell us if the problem goes away.

Comment: 2/3 of the includes you use are superfluous / unused. Note that including C headers (`<string.h>`, `<stdio.h>`) is deprecated. Use `<cstring>` and `<cstdio>` instead. Better even, don't include C headers at all.

Answer (score 1):

1. Possibility

As stated by **@– n. 'pronouns'** in the comment, this should probably be no issue, because getline is expected to return false if stream not opened, but could try (maybe stdlib implementation bug):

In this part:

```
inputFile.open("_coefs.txt");
if (!inputFile)
    cout<< "Error";
count=0;
while (std::getline(inputFile, lines) && !lines.empty())
```

on error you are still reading from invalid stream object.

Should be something like:

```
inputFile.open("_coefs.txt");
if (!inputFile) {
    cout<< "Error";
    return 1;
}
```

2. Possibility

The string being read is too long (file too big and no '\n')

Comment: `std::getline(inputFile, lines)` will simply return `false` in this case and the loop won't execute at all.

Comment: I agree that this holds by reading from an opened stream. but I'm not sure if this is also guaranteed by the standard if the stream is not opened at all - maybe you could link to the relevant documentation where this is clearly guaranteed ?

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely overflowing the `ft_means` array:

Add the `<< add this` lines as shown below and run your code again and see what happens.

```
  while (std::getline(inputFile, lines) && !lines.empty())
  {
    if (count >= FEATURE)                                     // << add this
    {                                                         // << add this
      std::cout << "I'm overflowing the ft_means array!!\n";  // << add this
      exit(1);  // or 'return 1' if exit(1) does not compile  // << add this
    }                                                         // << add this

    std::istringstream(lines) >> ft_means[count];
    count++;
  }
```

As already mentioned you should use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

Or maybe you could use `std::array` as a replacement for raw arrays. Debug builds usually show when you write to an `std::array` out of bounds.